# python cumulative sum of triples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My data is:

```
li = [('a', 10, 'b'), ('b', 12, 'c'), ('c', 5, 'd'), ('b', 2, 'e')]
```

`a` is the start.

The execution should be as:

```
a = 0
b = a + 10
c = b + 12
d = c + 5
e = b + 2
```

S in the end:

```
a=0 b=10 c=22 d=27 e=12
```

I thought about using trees and recursion to calculate, but I’m at a loss and don’t know how to write these codes.

Answer (score 3):

Using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will make this task pretty simple:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
for source, operand, target in li:
    res[target] = res[source] + operand

for key,val in res.items():
    print(key, "=", val)
```

Will give:

```
a = 0
b = 10
c = 22
d = 27
e = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You need direct access to your variables in namespace?

```py
from sys import modules

main = modules["__main__"]

li=[('a',10,'b'),('b',12,'c'),('c',5,'d'),('b',2,'e')]

a = 0
for var_1, num, var_2 in li:
    setattr(main, var_2, getattr(main, var_1) + int(num))

print(f"a={a}", f"b={b}", f"c={c}", f"d={d}", f"e={e}", sep='\n')
```

output:

```
a=0
b=10
c=22
d=27
e=12
```